# The equality of $n\times n$ matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

The following statement is **false (the answer)**. I am unsure how to go about solving this equation. I do not have any useful notes to provide to this post as all of my notes are algebraic attempts to solve this equation.

Let $A$, $B$ and $C$ be $(n \times n)$ matrices with $B$ and $A-2I$ invertible. Suppose $ABC = 2CB + A^2$. Then $C = (A-2I)^{-1}B^{-1}A^2$.

So how does one go about solving this equation.(Please do not down vote, this is a honest question and I have put much effort in my attempts to solve it). Thanks everybody!

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume $BC=CB$. Then $ABC=2BC+A^2$ or
$$
(A-2I)BC=A^2
$$
and so
$$
C=B^{-1}(A-2I)^{-1}A^2
$$
However, this is generally different from $(A-2I)^{-1}B^{-1}A^2$.

Conversely, if $C=B^{-1}(A-2I)^{-1}A^2$, then $BC=(A-2I)^{-1}A^2=A^2(A-2I)^{-1}$ so
$$
A^3(A-2I)^{-1}=2CB+A^2
$$
and
$$
A^3=2CB(A-2I)+A^2(A-2I)
$$
that gives
$$
2CB(A-2I)=2A^2
$$
and
$$
CB=A^2(A-2I)^{-1}=BC
$$